# Finding the limit of $( 1 + a + a^2 + \ldots+ a^n)/(1 + b + b^2 + \ldots+ b^n)$

Tags: limits

I have some problems finding the limit of $$\frac{ 1 + a + a^2 +\cdots + a^n}{1 + b + b^2 + \cdots + b^n}.$$
$0\le a,b \le +∞$

Here is what I got :

> Forcefuly factorize $a^n$ and $b^n$ :
>      $$ \frac{a^n ( 1 + \frac1{a} + \frac1{a^2} + ... + \frac1{a^n})}{b^n( 1 + \frac1{b} + ... + \frac1{b^n})} 
>       = \left(\frac ab\right)^n\cdot \frac{\dfrac{1-\frac{1}a^{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}a}}{\dfrac{1-\frac{1}b^{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}b}} $$

From here I'm kinda stuck since I don't know the limit of $\left(\frac ab\right)^n$ unless I take all the possible cases. Same goes for the other part.

I want to know the next step into solving this limit.

Comment: Do you mean the limit as $a, b \to \infty$, or as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: I need the limit for n -> ∞. a,b are constants from ( 0, +∞ )

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hopital?

Comment: Might be, I don't know the name tho.

Comment: The method I tried turned out to give a wrong answer, so I deleted my answer. Writing out all 9 cases is not that bad, honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $a$ and $b$ parts of your fraction have their own limits, without taking any ratio.  When $a$ and $b$ are both less than $1$, this answers the question.  When $a$ or $b$ is $\geq 1$, both parts have $+\infty$ as their limit, but they are getting there at very different rates (or the same rate when $a=b$) and this solves the other case.

There should be no need to use L'Hopital rule, and there are indeed potentially $9$ cases, but most of them require no calculation.  The significant cases are the ones in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Sooo... I basicaly have to write all the 9 cases ? Cause that's what I was afraid of.

Comment: After dispensing of $a=b$ you have $8$ cases, for which you can roughly divide the work in half using symmetry (switching $a$ and $b$ takes the reciprocal of the answer), but the book-keeping is not so bad and you don't have to work out $8$ ($4$) cases because either both values are less than $1$ in absolute value, or the larger of the two is $\geq 1$, so really two nontrivial cases to work out.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1+a+\cdots+a^n}{1+b+\cdots+b^n}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1-b}{1-a}.\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-b^{n+1}}=\frac{1-b}{1-a}$ if $1<a\leq b$.